# Can't delete multiple array elements in one run

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Today I started working on a internet filter so parents can configurate that their kids can't look at several websites.

I'm struggling with a keyword problem. If I try to delete all keywords, it only deletes the last made keyword. When I look in the console, I don't see any errors. I have to close my extension and open it to delete the next keyword. I think it has to do with the .addEventListener(), but I'm not sure.

Here's my code:

```
// Checking if this program didn't run earlier then set "keywords"
chrome.storage.sync.get("keywords", function(result){
    if(result.keywords == undefined){
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"keywords":[]});
    }
});

// All HTML content
var keywordsdiv = document.getElementById("keywords");
var newkeyword = document.getElementById("newkeyword");
var addbutton = document.getElementById("add");
addbutton.addEventListener("click", function(){addkeyword(newkeyword.value)});
var keywords = [];

// Collect all information on Chrome storage and put in in the keywords
chrome.storage.sync.get("keywords", function(result){
    keywords = result.keywords;
    keywords.forEach(_);
    function _(keyword){
        keywordsdiv.innerHTML += "<div class=\"keyword\" id=\"" + keyword + "\">" + keyword + "</div>";
        document.getElementById(keyword).addEventListener("click", function(){removekeyword(keyword)});
    }
});


// Remove the keyword
function removekeyword(keyword){
    document.getElementById(keyword).remove();
    chrome.storage.sync.get("keywords", function(result){
        var newkeywords = result.keywords;
        newkeywords.forEach(_);
        var bool = false;
        function _(_keyword, index){
            if(bool){
                newkeywords[index - 1] = _keyword;
            }
            if(keyword == _keyword){
                bool = true;
            }
            if(bool && index === newkeywords.length - 1){
                newkeywords.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        keywords = newkeywords;
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"keywords":newkeywords});
    });
}

// Adding the keyword
function addkeyword(keyword){
    keywordsdiv.innerHTML += "<div class=\"keyword\" id=\"" + keyword + "\">" + keyword + "</div>";
    keywords[keywords.length] = keyword;
    document.getElementById(keyword).addEventListener("click", function(){removekeyword(keyword)});
    newkeyword.value = "";
    chrome.storage.sync.get("keywords", function(result){
        var newkeywords = result.keywords;
        newkeywords[newkeywords.length] = keyword;
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"keywords":newkeywords});
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is your code to remove all keywords? `removekeyword` only removes one keyword.

Comment: @Barmar I meaned: to click all the keywords

Comment: So I guess what you mean: only the last keyword gets assigned a click listener. Is that correct?

Comment: The problem is with `keywordsdiv.innerHTML +=`. This rewrites the HTML of the DIV. This creates new `keyword` DIVs for all the old keywords, and these don't have event listeners attached. You should use `appendChild`.

Comment: @Barmar Excellent catch, but _please_ make that into an answer. Don't answer in comments.

Comment: I was in the process, just wanted to leave a preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the HTML with `keyworddiv.innerHTML += ...` loses all the old event listeners, because you're recereating all the old DIVs. Use `keyworddiv.appendChild()` to add new DIVs without disturbing the old ones. The new code in `addkeyword` is:

```
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = 'keyword';
  newDiv.id = keyword;
  newDiv.innerHTML = keyword;
  newDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
    removekeyword(keyword)
  });
  keywordsdiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

I also changed the code that restores the keywords from `chrome.storage` to call this function, so I don't have to duplicate it.

Here's the full, executable code.

```js
// Checking if this program didn't run earlier then set "keywords"
chrome.storage && chrome.storage.sync.get("keywords", function(result) {
  if (result.keywords == undefined) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      "keywords": []
    });
  }
});

// All HTML content
var keywordsdiv = document.getElementById("keywords");
var newkeyword = document.getElementById("newkeyword");
var addbutton = document.getElementById("add");
addbutton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addkeyword(newkeyword.value)
});
var keywords = [];

// Collect all information on Chrome storage and put in in the keywords
chrome.storage && chrome.storage.sync.get("keywords", function(result) {
  keywords = result.keywords;
  keywords.forEach(addkeyword);
});


// Remove the keyword
function removekeyword(keyword) {
  document.getElementById(keyword).remove();
  chrome.storage && chrome.storage.sync.get("keywords", function(result) {
    var newkeywords = result.keywords;
    newkeywords.forEach(_);
    var bool = false;

    function _(_keyword, index) {
      if (bool) {
        newkeywords[index - 1] = _keyword;
      }
      if (keyword == _keyword) {
        bool = true;
      }
      if (bool && index === newkeywords.length - 1) {
        newkeywords.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    keywords = newkeywords;
    chrome.storage && chrome.storage.sync.set({
      "keywords": newkeywords
    });
  });
}

// Adding the keyword
function addkeyword(keyword) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = 'keyword';
  newDiv.id = keyword;
  newDiv.innerHTML = keyword;
  newDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
    removekeyword(keyword)
  });
  keywordsdiv.appendChild(newDiv);
  keywords.push(keyword);
  newkeyword.value = "";
  chrome.storage && chrome.storage.sync.get("keywords", function(result) {
    var newkeywords = result.keywords;
    newkeywords[newkeywords.length] = keyword;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      "keywords": newkeywords
    });
  });
}
```

```html
Keywords:
<div id="keywords"></div>
New:
<input type="text" id="newkeyword" />
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: Could you please trim that down to only the changed code?

Comment: @Xan Then it won't be executable.

Comment: It still isn't. `chrome.storage` is not exposed to the web. No need for a snippet here.

Comment: I know, that's why I added `chrome.storage &&` tests. But the code that adds and removes keywords from the live page works. Anyway, I extracted the changes into the main explanation at the top